# Neighborhoods for continuous functions between CG spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have a couple of problems regarding the existence of certain neighborhoods, so as to prove continuity of suitable functions.

Suppose then that $Y,X$ and $Z$ are compactly-generated Hausdorff spaces (I use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space) definition of compactly generated).

1. Let $f\colon Y\to X$ be a continuous function and suppose that $C$ is a compact subset of $Y$. **It should be true that**, given any $y\in C$ and any neighborhood $U$ of $f(y)$, there exists a neighborhood $M$ of $y$ in $C$ (so, $C$ has the subspace topology) such that $f(\overline{M})\subseteq U$.
2. Let $Z\Box Y$ be the $k-$fication of $Z\times Y$. Thus, $Z\Box Y$ is the cartesian product $Z\times Y$ with the topology whose family of closed sets is given by those $A\subseteq Z\times Y$ such that, for each compact $K$ of $Z\times Y$ (with the product topology), $A\cap K$ is closed in $K$. ($Z\Box Y$ is compactly-generated Hausdorff and its compact sets are exactly those of $Z\times Y$ with the product topology). Suppose now that $h\colon Z\Box Y\to X$ is a continuous function and define the map $k\colon Z\to Hom_{\mathbf{Set}}(Y,X)$ which sends $z\in Z$ to $k(z):=h(z, -)$. It's not difficult to show that $k(z)$ is actually continuous, so $k\colon Z\to Hom_{\mathbf{Top}}(Y,X)$. Suppose now that, for $z\in Z$, there are an open $U$ in $X$ and a compact $C$ in $Y$ such that $k(z)(C)\subseteq U$. **It should be true that**, since $U$ is open, $C$ is compact and $h$ is continuous (these are the suggestions I am given), there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $z$ such that $h(V\times C)\subseteq U$.

I cannot prove the two facts described in the lines starting with the bold words.

As far as the first point is concerned, I can see that, by continuity, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $y$ in $C$ such that $f(N)\subseteq U$, so the problem is the presence of the closure. How can I get rid of it?

Concerning the second point, I noticed that, by continuity of $h$, for each $(z,y)\in B:=\{z\}\times C$ there is a neighborhood $W_{y}$ of $(z,y)$ in $Z\Box Y$ such that $h(W_{y})\subseteq U$. Then $\{B\cap W_{y}\}_{y\in Y}$ is an open covering of $B$, hence, since $B$ is compact, I can extract a finite subcovering from it. But I can not go any further with this.

Any idea about how to solve these issues? Thank you for your help.